# CSS: Image to float in the middle of justify-aligned text

Tags: css

Is there any way at all to make an image floating in the middle of a justify-aligned text?

I don't mind hacks, but the text needs to be editable.

[image: Image floating in the middle]

If anyone wants to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vb6dL/

`Please ignore this line (required by SO)`

Comment: Actually it's weird that something like that didn't land in CSS3.

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't possible at this point in time to float an image in the centre of a block of text with css.

Here is a hack that comes close:

- http://css-tricks.com/float-center/

And some further reading on the issue:

- http://www.codeitpretty.com/2012/05/you-cant-float-center.html